# How can I manipulate the `get_price_html()` function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website, with WooCommerce functionality.

I have created a Custom Field, which appears on the Product Pages, which allows shoppers to enter their own custom text.  This custom text will then be engraved onto the associated product, with my client wanting to charge £2 per letter entered.  My client has also requested for the Product Price to update, in real time, as and when a shopper enters/removes a letter in the custom field.

Therefore, I need to manipulate the `get_price_html()` function as to Output the sum of the following equation:

> Current Product Price + (Character Count * £2)

In order to generate the Character Count, I have entered the following jQuery Code into the Single Product Template:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);
jQuery(document).on('keydown', '.product-custom-text', updateCount);

function updateCount() {
    var cs = jQuery(this).val().length;
    jQuery('#letter_count').text(cs);
}
</script>
```

Then to Output the Character Count, I entered the next bit of coding into the `functions.php` file:

```
function custom_letter_counter(){
    echo '<span id="letter_count"></span>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_letter_counter');
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction as to the next step I would need to do, in order to manipulate/override the `get_price_html()` function as to reflect the sum of the above equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit vague on what you're asking, because changing the HTML of the price doesn't actually change the product price itself.

1. You'll need to add a custom input box for the text that needs to be engraved
2. You'll then need to hook into the cart and append this custom field value to the product
3. You'll need to calculate the total price by counting how many characters there are once the product is being added to the cart
4. You'll then need to hook the custom field to the order data, so it can be reviewed later

Here's how to accomplish all of these...

First lets add the text input:

```
function add_engrave_text_field() {
    echo '<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label>Engrave Text</label></td>
                    <td class="value">
                        <label><input type="text" name="engrave_text" placeholder="Engrave Text" /> £2 per letter</label>                        
                    </td>
                </tr>                             
            </tbody>
        </table>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_engrave_text_field' );
```

Then we append this to the cart order once the user hits the 'add to cart' button:

```
function save_engrave_text( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['engrave_text'] ) && !empty( $_POST['engrave_text'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[ "engrave_text" ] = esc_attr( $_POST['engrave_text'] );     
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_engrave_text', 99, 2 );
```

Then we calculate how much it will cost in total with the text that needs to be engraved:

```
function calculate_engrave_text_fee( $cart_object ) {  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        if( isset( $value["engrave_text"] ) ) {
            // Get how many characters there are
            $chars = strlen( $value["engrave_text"] );
            // Calculate the character count by 2 (£2)
            $engrave_text_fee = $chars * 2;
            $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->price );
            $value['data']->set_price( $orgPrice + $engrave_text_fee );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_engrave_text_fee', 99 );
```

(optional) You can render the engrave text on the cart/checkout per product:

```
function render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item = null ) {
    $meta_items = array();

    /* Woo 2.4.2 updates */
    if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) {
        $meta_items = $cart_data;
    }

    if( isset( $cart_item["engrave_text"] ) ) {
        $meta_items[] = array( "name" => "Engrave Text", "value" => $cart_item["engrave_text"] );
    }

    return $meta_items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout', 99, 2 );
```

And lastly you'll need to add the following to make the engrave text appear on emails, orders, etc.

```
function engrave_text_order_meta_handler( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset( $values["engrave_text"] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "Engrave Text", $values["engrave_text"] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'engrave_text_order_meta_handler', 99, 3 );
```

This was copied from an old project of mine and modified to suit your own needs, so it's not fully tested. Debugging should be fairly straightforward, as documentation on WooCommerce is plentiful.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  I had already created a Custom Input field which Outputs the amount of letters inserted.  That said, I removed all my own efforts and implemented yours.  Whilst it inserts the Custom Text Field, it does not have an affect on the price itself.  Is there anything else I would need to include?

Comment: I've updated the `calculate_engrave_text_fee` method to make it work with the latest version of WC and it's all working on my end now (tested it for myself)

Comment: Thanks for the further modifications.  Unfortunately, it still does not work on the site.  I deactivated the few Plugins I had, leaving just the WooCommerce Plugin Active, with no success.  I also checked to ensure that I had the latest version of WooCommerce.  Can you see there being any other issues that could be preventing this code from working?

Comment: No issues on my end. It's doing it all correctly. I'd recommend clearing transients from Woocommerce>System status>Tools as that can sometimes affect things. Also, clear out your cart or better yet use Chrome Incognito mode to make sure Woocommerce isn't using some cached stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestive.  Tried them all but still to no success.  I will have to have a play around.  If I come across anything, I will let you know.  For the time being, is there no 'if statements' that I could use which would say 'if shopper inputs 2 characters into Custom Field, add £2 to 'get_price_html()' etc?  I've tried various code but to no success unfortunately.

Comment: You can use a filter to wrap the price in its own tag to make it easier updating it via jQuery, here's a link: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1636-1652. Once you've wrapped the price in an element, you can do this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWvzdG

Comment: I have managed to successfully enter the HTML code, however I cannot seem to generate the character and thus produce the required increments to the original price.  Could it be that the provided js code is not suitable for WordPress?  I had a similar problem a while back whereby the js code had to be changed as the '$' entries were not compatible with WordPress.  Unfortunately, I was not aware of what changes were made.  Could this be a possibility?

Comment: Since every theme is different, I can't give you an exact answer. I've given you plenty of examples on how you can easily get this done, but it seems like you're inexperienced. I'd recommend checking out the WordPress Codex, WooCommerce API docs and jQuery docs.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  After a little bit of tinkering, I have finally achieved what was needed. :-)